# How do I cache lookup data with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

I'm learning my way around EF, and I know caching is faster than a round trip to the DB for things like state, country, etc. But I'm not sure how to implement it. I was looking at this post ([entities from local cache](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-code-first-get-entities-from-local-cache-or-the-database)) that mentioned an extension, but is there something built in I should leverage?

I'd like to have a function like this that wouldn't have to go to the db every time:

```
public static int GetCountryId(string countryCode = "US")
{
    if (countryCode == string.Empty)
        countryCode = "US"; // Assume US
    return db.Country.Where
        (
            p => p.CountryCode == countryCode
        ).Select(p => p.CountryId).First();
}
```

***Updated:***

I'm now thinking about a GetCached function that would use generics to hold some lookup lists in memory. Somthing like this:

```
public class Lookups
{
    private static MkpContext db = new MkpContext();

    public static IEnumerable GetCached(CachedLists list)
    {
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        var listOut = cache[list.ToString()] as IEnumerable;
        if (listOut != null) return listOut;

        switch (list)
        {
            case CachedLists.Countries:
                cache.Set
                (
                    list.ToString(),
                    db.Country.ToList(),
                    new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now,new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0))
                );
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }

        listOut = cache[list.ToString()] as IEnumerable;
        return listOut;
    }

}    

public enum CachedLists
{
    Countries,
}
```

But the above solution would leave me with an un-typed Enumerable. I'd love to be able to specify the types somehow, or better yet, do some sort of extension.

Comment: as far as I know since EF 5, the query will be cached automatically for you. You don't need to cache it manually. Unless what you actually want to cache is the data. For your method, to make a local cache, you can simply make some Dictionary with Key as `countryCode` and Value as the `CountryID`, then perform the look up everytime `countryCode` is found, otherwise fetch it from db (in which the query should be cached if done once - the whole code will almost equal to the ADO.NET query, no time needed to compile LinqToEntity to SQL query any more).

Comment: When  you say the query is cached but not the data, what do you mean? Do you mean that it would still have to talk to the database, just not recreate the query? I would like to save trips to the DB. Our Country table has ID, Code, and Name. (ex. 1, "US", "United States")

Comment: Without query being cached, your LinqToEntity query will be first compiled to expression tree, then to Entity SQL, and finally to SQL query. That will be repeated every time the query is executed. but with query being cached, that will be done just 1 time. Meaning the SQL query will always be ready to be executed like as you use the raw `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` in ADO.NET, so it will be faster. This however will make a trip to your db. So as you said, it seems not what you want.

Comment: In my case I use the list to populate a combo box. So I am just thinking of storing it as a list somewhere, and wondering where.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options, but here's one approach that will work well if users are mostly querying the same few country codes:

Create a [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) instance to use as a static, private, readonly field on your class. In your method, try to get a cached item from this cache if there is one with the given `countryCode` as its key. If it's not there, do your database query and Add the result into the cache before returning it.

By the way, the approach in the article you linked probably isn't a very good approach: it will only help if you've already got data in the specific database context instance that you're dealing with, and usually it's best for your contexts to be short-lived. It's also really CPU-intensive to compile an expression into a function, and then run that function against every entity that the context has cached, just to find out whether the item is there or not. If you then find out that it's not there, and you have to go back to the database anyway, you just wasted time and resources.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have proposed is usually what I do to return cached data.

However data is cached as an object and therefor you have to return it as the object you expect.

Lets assume that your country class is represented by:

```
public class Country
{
    #region Constructors

    public Country(string code, string name)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

What we need to do is look up our cache by a given key, if exists return the cache, otherwise get from database - same logic as you did.

Difference is here `var listOut = cache[list.ToString()] as IEnumerable;`

You want to check whether the value for that key `is` of type `Country`

If we define a `GetCache` method as following:

```
    static object GetCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        if (Cache[cacheKey] is object cachedResult)
        {
            return cachedResult;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

What we need to do in order to return a `List<Country>` is

```
        if (GetCache(cacheKey) is List<Country> cachedData)
        {
            return cachedData;
        }
```

Now instead of a list of object we have a `List<Country>`

I have made a simple console app to show the result - hope it helps:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    #region Usings

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Caching;

    #endregion

    class Program
    {
        #region Fields

        private static readonly ObjectCache Cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //simulates app life span
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var countries = GetData();
                foreach (var country in countries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(country.Name);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static List<Country> GetData()
        {
            string cacheKey = "Country-Lookup";

            if (GetCache(cacheKey) is List<Country> cachedData)
            {
                return cachedData;
            }

            // otherwise do some logic stuff and get from DB

            //db data simulation
            List<Country> coutries = new List<Country>
            {
                new Country("IT", "Italy"),
                new Country("UK", "United Kindom"),
                new Country("US", "United States")
            };

            //add to cache
            AddToCache(cacheKey, coutries);

            return coutries;
        }

        static object GetCache(string cacheKey)
        {
            if (Cache[cacheKey] is object cachedResult)
            {
                return cachedResult;
            }

            return null;
        }

        static void AddToCache(string cacheKey, object dataToCache)
        {
            if (dataToCache == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Cache.Set(cacheKey, dataToCache, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use EntityFramework Plus.

```
public static int GetCountryId(string countryCode = "US")
{
    return db.Country.Where
        (
            p => p.CountryCode == countryCode
        ).Select(p => p.CountryId).First();
}
```

Would probably become...

```
public static int GetCountryId(string countryCode = "US")
{
    using var context = new Context();
    var allCountries = context.Country
                    .FromCache({cachePolicy})
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.CountryCode);
    return allCountries[countryCode];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however I don't see any FromCache property for DbSet

Comment: You need to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/

Answer (score 0):

For something basic like mapping a country code to a countryId I'd suggest keeping it simple and using a dictionary. If this is happening inside a web application you'll want to use a ConcurrentDictionary to handle multiple threads hitting the code, otherwise a normal dictionary will be fine.

You could also have some code that populates the dictionary when the app starts up to make the experience even snappier for users.

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> countryLookup = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

public static int GetCountryId(string countryCode = "US")
{
    if (countryCode == string.Empty)
        countryCode = "US"; // Assume US

    if (countryLookup.TryGetValue(countryCode, out int countryId))
        return countryId;

    var countryId = db.Country
        .First(p => p.CountryCode == countryCode)
        .CountryId;

    countryLookup.TryAdd(countryCode, countryId);
    return countryId;
}
```